# String anagrams grouping | Improvements and Analyzing time complexity

Tags: java, string, data-structures, time-complexity, anagram

Following is editorial solution approach to Leetcode problem [49. Group Anagrams](https://leetcode.com/problems/group-anagrams/).

##### Problem statement

Given an array of strings strs, group **the anagrams** together. You can return the answer in **any order**.

##### Example

```
Input: strs = ["eat","tea","tan","ate","nat","bat"]
Output: [["bat"],["nat","tan"],["ate","eat","tea"]]
```

##### My understanding

1. Create a unique identifier(a key) for each string, so that they can be matched against `key` and can be grouped together in a `Map`.
2. Once done grouping as `Map<String, List<String>>` with `K=KeyString` and `Value=Anagrams`
3. Lastly collect all values from the map and return as a `List`.

I understood the notion for using the `count[]`.

This particular version of solution creates a key using `freq count` method instead of sorting(Sorting approach incur extra `n*logn` time, where as this freq-count technique cost only `linear time`)

##### Solution approach

```java
class Solution {
    public List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {
        if (strs.length == 0) 
          return new ArrayList();

        Map<String, List> ans = new HashMap<String, List>();
        int[] count = new int[26];

        for (String s : strs) {

            Arrays.fill(count, 0); // Cost extra O(26) every time. Can we use count = new int[26]??

            for (char c : s.toCharArray()){
              count[c - 'a']++;
            } 

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                sb.append('#');
                sb.append(count[i]);
            }

            String key = sb.toString();

            if (!ans.containsKey(key)) 
              ans.put(key, new ArrayList());

            ans.get(key).add(s);
        }
        return new ArrayList(ans.values());
    }
}
```

`Time Complexity` : `O(NK)`, where `N` is the length of `strs`, and `K` is the maximum length of a string in strs.

`Space Complexity` : `O(NK)`, the total information content stored in ans.

##### Questions

1. Since, we need to keep count of characters for all `N` string in input, we need to reset, the count every time as `Arrays.fill(count, 0)`. This cost extra O(26) every time. Can we use `count = new int[26]`? Will it improve the time spent in resetting the each index value to `0`?
2. I can not understand the use of `#` while preparing the key for anagram. What purpose does it fulfills ?
3. Can we use `trie`  or `heap` or any other relevant DS to solve this problem?

Comment: Regarding #2, consider what would happen without the `#`s. Specifically, let's consider just strings over {a, b}. The string `aaaaaaaaaaab` will have `key="111"` (11 `a`s, 1 `b`). The string `abbbbbbbbbbb` will have the same key. With `#`s between the letters, they are different (`11#1` vs `1#11`).

Comment: Gotcha! `#` is just a token to split the count of the codepoints. Then there might be a case where where `#` itself is a part of the input string, could be possible , right? Or any `unicode` character, in such case how to handle count representation?

Comment: I guess, in such situation, we need to come up with some sort of encoding or hash to generate a unique key.

Comment: Using `Trie` would probably yield same complexity time and space wise that you're obtaining in your answer.